# Change column name every nth column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, r-colnames

So I have created a **data.frame** that has n columns like so:

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(nrow = 3, ncol = 15))
```

It looks like this:

```
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15
1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
2 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
3 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

I want **change every Nth column name**, so it looks like this:

```
  A  V2 V3 B  V5 V6 C  V8 V9  D  V11 V12  E  V14 V15
1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
2 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
3 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

I have made this sequence, that gives me colnames I want:

```
colnames(df[,seq(1,ncol(df),3)])
```

**The output:**

```
[1] "V1"  "V4"  "V7"  "V10" "V13"
```

But when I try to change names **nothing happens:**

```
colnames(df[,seq(1,ncol(df),3)]) <- c("A","B","C","D","E")
```

I also tried this, but it **only changes the first column** and it gives warning message:

```
names <- colnames(df[,seq(1,ncol(df),3)])
colnames(df)[colnames(df) == names] <- c("A","B","C","D","E")
```

**The warning message:**

```
Warning message:
In colnames(df)[colnames(df) == names] <- c("A", "B", "C", "D",  :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Thank you in advance for your help, I appreciate every answer :)

Comment: Try `colnames(df)[seq(1,ncol(df),3)] <- c("A","B","C","D","E")` .

Comment: It works now that I reset RStudio. Probably some bug :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify certain column names based on the position, but you need to put the `[]` brackets outside the `colnames` function:

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(nrow = 3, ncol = 15))
colnames(df)[seq(1,ncol(df),3)] <- c("A","B","C","D","E")
df
#>    A V2 V3  B V5 V6  C V8 V9  D V11 V12  E V14 V15
#> 1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA NA  NA  NA
#> 2 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA NA  NA  NA
#> 3 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA NA  NA  NA
```

Comment: well...what to say...I also tried it, but it did not work...then I reset my Rstudio and it works... :D :D thank you very much. In 10 min I will accept your answer.

Comment: you can also use `%%` here if you want too: 
`colnames(df)[seq(colnames(df)) %%3 == 1] <- c("A","B","C","D","E")`

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this code. The value `k` allows modifying the spacing in names:

```
#Data
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(nrow = 3, ncol = 15))
#Seq for names
k <- 3
v1 <- seq(1,length(names(df)),by=k)
vchar <- LETTERS[1:length(v1)]
#Replace
names(df)[v1] <- vchar
```

Output:

```
   A V2 V3  B V5 V6  C V8 V9  D V11 V12  E V14 V15
1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA NA  NA  NA
2 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA NA  NA  NA
3 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA NA  NA  NA
```